# How to include a public module located in a subfolder

Tags: rust

I have the following project where I want to divide some modules into subfolders.
The current file structure is simply:

```
src/
  ->main.rs
  ->cpu/
      ->cpu.rs
```

main.rs only contains:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let c : cpu::Cpu;
    cpu::thing();
}
```

and cpu/cpu.rs contains a struct declaration and a test function:

```
pub struct Cpu {
    memory : [u8; 16],
}


pub fn thing() -> u8 {
2 // whatever, it's a test
}
```

How do I include the cpu.rs public functions and structs into main.rs?
No matter what I try, I get an error (`` could not find `cpu` in the crate root ``) if I use `use crate::cpu::{Cpu, thing};`, and using `mod cpu;` seems to only work on the same directory.

Searching for solutions online is extremely infuriating, since the answers are mixed up between the 2015 and 2018 rust editions, are over-complicated or are done in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to made cpu (folder) a mod itself, you need to include a `mod.rs` file in the folder structure:

```
src/
  ->main.rs
  ->cpu/
      ->mod.rs
      ->cpu.rs
```

and in `mod.rs` reexport publicly the inner `cpu` module:

```rust
pub mod cpu;
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't using `mod.rs` discouraged? (Again, I found mixed responses regarding `mod.rs` in guides and other questions). What would be the Rust 2018 way of doing this if so?

Comment: @Lightsong uhm, I dont think there is another choice if you want to keep the folder. Otherwise just with cpu.rs file you should be able to call it from main unnesting a cpu in the modules calls.

Comment: alright, thanks! And how would the `use` look like in main.rs? I had to use `mod cpu;`and `use crate::cpu::cpu::{Cpu, thing};`, which looks extremely weird.

Comment: just use `mod cpu;` in main and then you can access it from ther; The crate stuff is ok also.

Comment: If I use only `mod cpu;`, I have to write `cpu::cpu::thing()`, doesn't it look a bit...ugly?

Comment: @Lightsong, bring it to the scope with the crate::cpu::.... call

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean that I have to duplicate the `cpu` keyword, both when bringing the stuff into scope with `crate::cpu::cpu::{Cpu, thing};` and when I don't. Is that normal?

Comment: It is normal yes, at least how I am used to it :)

Comment: If you don't want the duplicated `cpu`, then don't duplicate it in your file hierarchy: either get rid of the `cpu` folder and have `cpu.rs` in the same folder as `main.rs`, or put the contents of `cpu.rs` directly in `cpu/mod.rs`.

Comment: @Jmb, I think he meant that is duplicated with the `mod X` and use `crate::X::...`